# Script triggered by new row appearing in sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a snapData script sourced externally and shown below:

```
    function snapData() {

    // get current sheet and tabs 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); var current = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (management)'); var database = ss.getSheetByName('Fees (data)');

    // count rows to snap var current_rows = current.getLastRow(); 
    var database_rows = database.getLastRow() + 1; 
    var database_rows_new = current_rows + database_rows - 2; 
    var rows_new = current.getRange("A2:F" + current_rows).getValues();

    // snap rows, can run this on a trigger to be timed 
    database.getRange("A" + database_rows + ":F" + database_rows_new).setValues(rows_new);

    }
```

At the moment, it is triggered by pressing the 'Run' button, however I would like to have the script triggered by a new row appearing on another tab.

Help with this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the [onChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) trigger

Comment: The onChange trigger can check if the user added a new row to the interface, not the value from `getLastRow`. This is a bit tricky as you need the value of the number of rows before the edit stored somewhere.

Comment: `current_rows` is defined in the above code. Is it a global?

Comment: I've had a look at onChange. When I click 'Add Trigger' I can choose the function to run, then select 'From spreadsheet' and 'On change', but it doesn't actually give me the option to select a particular sheet or columns that would trigger the function. I need to have the trigger action when a new row appears on a particular tab. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 1):

"I would like to have the script triggered by a new row appearing on another tab."

By using the installable trigger `onChange`, it is possible to trigger the script as planned. `source` is an Event Object returned by `onChange`, though it is not included in the [documnentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).

- `var sheetname = src.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()`: get the sheet name
- `var ctype = e.changeType;`: get the change type
- `if (sheetname === "target" && ctype === "INSERT_ROW"){`: test if the type was inserting a row on "target"

---

```
function so5899606501(e) {

  // return all the event objects
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));

  // get the source
  var src = e.source;
  var spreadsheetname = src.getName();
  var sheetname = src.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()
  Logger.log("spreadsheet = "+spreadsheetname+", sheet name = "+sheetname);
  var currentcell = src.getCurrentCell();
  Logger.log("the current cell = "+currentcell.getA1Notation());

  // get the change type
  var ctype = e.changeType;
  Logger.log("the change type is "+ctype);

  // test for the type of change
  if (ctype == "INSERT_ROW"){  
  Logger.log("A row was just inserted");
  }
  else
  {
  Logger.log("the change type wasnt a new row, it was "+ctype)
  }

  //test for the sheet where the change took place
  if (sheetname == "target"){  
  Logger.log("the change took place on the sheet named 'target'");
  }
  else
  {
  Logger.log("the change took place on the sheet named" +sheetname+".")
  }

  // test for the change type AND the sheet name
  if (sheetname == "target" && ctype == "INSERT_ROW"){
  Logger.log("Eureka!. A new row was inserted on the sheet named 'target. Lets do stuff");
  }
  else{
  Logger.log("Sigh. It either wasn't a new row AND/OR it wasn't on the sheet named 'target'. Either way, we can ignore it.");
  }

}
```